# Has alcoholism increased?

Tags: history, consumption

Has alcoholism increased since prohibition days? I've seen the sales outlets for alcohol availability rise since the days of the state liquor stores.
I checked the [National Institute on Alcohol Abuse and Alcoholism](https://www.niaaa.nih.gov/alcohol-health/overview-alcohol-consumption/alcohol-facts-and-statistics) and a news article from [NBC](https://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-news/americans-are-drinking-more-lot-more-n347126) without any specific results. Moved to [Health SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [Health SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: Should I move it to Health SE and delete it here or leave it here too.

Comment: Cross posting is generally discouraged, so either delete it here, or at least edit it to let folks know you've created a copy over there with a link to the new post if they're interested.

Comment: Is this the USA or the whole world?

Comment: The new question location is [here](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/14302).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [OECD](http://www.keepeek.com/Digital-Asset-Management/oecd/social-issues-migration-health/health-at-a-glance-2017_health_glance-2017-en#page74) (The Organization for Economic Cooperation and Development), alcohol consumption in its member countries (which includes the US) has been decreasing since [at least] 2000. Litres of pure alcohol consumed (a metric for standardizing alcohol consumption across drinks of varying alcohol content) has fallen from 9.5 litres per capita in 2000 to 9 litres in 2015 (roughly 5% decline).

The definition of alcoholism can vary since it typically includes the frequency of consumption within its own definition. The paper I cited includes stats on binge drinking (at least once a month) by gender, but does not compare data to prior years. There's been a ton of research on this topic, so a bit of googling should quickly turn up something useful. [CAMH](http://www.camh.ca/en/research/news_and_publications/reports_and_books/Pages/default.aspx) has useful publications and so does the [WHO](http://www.euro.who.int/en/health-topics/disease-prevention/alcohol-use/publications/2016/public-health-successes-and-missed-opportunities.-trends-in-alcohol-consumption-and-attributable-mortality-in-the-who-european-region,-19902014-2016).

Answer (score 0):

But, if you read this, it sounds like Alcohol consumption (along with all it's problems including addiction) has increased significantly in the USA. [This study](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/08/10/542409957/drinking-on-the-rise-in-u-s-especially-for-women-minorities-older-adults) is out just last summer (2017)

> "In the '90s, however, alcohol consumption increased — the percentage
>   of people who drank at all increased by nearly half, while high-risk
>   and disordered drinking increased by about 20 percent and 12 percent,
>   respectively."

If you go all the way back to Prohibition, then it has clearly [increased](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://static.vinepair.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/chart2.png&imgrefurl=http://digg.com/2017/history-of-american-alcohol-consumption&h=612&w=800&tbnid=plCgmP2nFMvupM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=209&usg=__0ua7GzjkOM2-EE9vnhwvKQiwfoY%3D&vet=10ahUKEwj-94PZjsbXAhUG0WMKHd3lDMEQ9QEILDAA..i&docid=ox_9Behu8jVFQM&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-94PZjsbXAhUG0WMKHd3lDMEQ9QEILDAA)

[image]